# webpack 3.0.0 in dependency but version 2.6.1 when node_modules/.bin/webpack --version

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, yarnpkg

Upgraded to `webpack: "^3.0.0` in devDependencies in package.json,

Still I see webpack 2.6.1 being used when running webpack command, when tried `node_modules/.bin/webpack --version` it shows **2.6.1** .

There is a dependency in the package json which has devDependencies on `webpack: "^2.6.0"` but should this impact webpack version in my repo?

Already tried:

- deleting node_modules
- updated global webpack to 3.x
- cleaned npm and yarn caches

P.S :  running project on node 4.2.0,windows 8.1 and yarn

Comment: what's the result of `npm ls webpack` ?

Comment: with webpack 3.0.0 it says `webpack@3.0.0  peer invalid`

Comment: @hackerrdave : so one of the dependents package has webpack 2.6.1 as peer dependency, ?

Comment: or I should say it doesn't have webpack 3 as peer dependency

Comment: do you see that "peer invalid" error during npm install?

Comment: have you tried clearing you cache via `npm cache clean`. also may help to post the whole package.json (or at least the dependency in question that is introducting conflict webpack version)

Comment: @hackerrdave : already tried cleaning cache, updated in question too :)

Comment: @hackerrdave : I got an error in npm install `webpack@3.7.1: wanted: {"node":">=4.3.0 <5.0.0 || >=5.10"} (current: {"node":"4.2.0","npm":"2.14.7"})` , will update node version and try. Thanks

Comment: Ah yea thats the answer - webpack 3 requires node version 4.3 or higher